# Rating and Like System Managment

Tags: php, database, optimization, database-design

I'm trying to integrate a rating and like system as part of a package to send to the end user (with unknown progamming skill).
My problem is how to manage the users (registered or not) that have already done an action.
At this moment I'm using PHP session to keep stored for a week the information, but this isn't a good solution.
Is it a good solution creating 2 tables (one for rating and one for like) to store the information? If I use this solution what's the most useful and "correct" information to retrieve if the user is not registered? And is it user-friendly?
I have thought to store: username and the ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extend the members's table with at least two new columns, likes and rating or create a new table (as you said) including the memberID with a reference(and an index) to store and select the data. I believe it's the best way. Unfortunately, in this case non-members cannot press like or rate, but it is a good reason for one to register. –

Comment: I need to create a new table,beacuse I can't modify what already exists and I don't know if the site has got a register form.However thanks for the id insteda of the username

Comment: a new table is better. if you don't have registration unique ID for every member, what you only have are session_ids.